# RobotFramework error - TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_log_path'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to install and use RobotFramework for the first time. I've done all the installations and have a test robot that simply tries to open Chrome. Every time I run it, I get the following error...

TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_log_path'

Here are my installed environment
Macbook M1 Pro
Chrome Version 114.0.5735.106 (Official Build) (arm64)
Python 3.11
PyCharm 2023.1.2 CE
Robotframework 6.0.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.1.0
selenium 4.10.0
chromedriver 114.0.5735.90

I've completely reinstalled everything but Chrome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use selenium 4.9.1 for the time being:
pip install selenium==4.9.1

Answer (score 5):

That error is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that `service_log_path` has been removed from the `__init__`, but there is now another way of passing it in. Here's a code snippet on passing `service_log_path` via the `service` arg in the new version:

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(
    executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver',
    service_log_path=os.devnull,
)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If that part is supposed to be done by Robot Framework directly, you should reach out to them on their GitHub page and open an issue directly with them: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework