# How to launch chrome in headless mode for selenium =4.10.0

Tags: python, robotframework, ui-automation

I tired below code:

${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver

```
call method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --headless
call method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
call method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
call method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
Set Global Variable    ${global_downloadDir}    ${CURDIR}\\Downloads\\
${disabled}    Create List    Chrome PDF Viewer
${prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${global_downloadDir}     plugins.plugins_disabled=${disabled}
Call Method    ${chrome options}   add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}  
maximize browser window
```

But getting below error:
WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'

Comment: It seems the same question was asked before: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76433782/robotframework-error-typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword). I checked the receipt from here and it works. E.g.  for packages:    `robotframework-seleniumlibrary  6.0.0`,  `selenium 4.9.1`
works `Open Browser    browser=Chrome  options=${chrome options}` or `Create WebDriver   Chrome  chrome_options=${chrome options}`